# How can I detect if a Scala Play Framework app is running on console mode?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have some code that warms up my app's caches that I'd like to run in production or when I start my app with `sbt run`. However, when I run `sbt console`, I'd like to skip this code so that I can get to testing on the REPL very quickly without any delays.

Is there a way to detect if my app is being run within `sbt console` so that I can avoid warming up the caches?

Comment: Why not just use a sys property? Either to disable/enable...

Comment: Great suggestion. I've added a `cache.warmup-delay` system property and set it to `-1` to disable warmup in my `build.sbt` within `initialCommands in console`.